# Trigger a function every x amount of time

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

so uhm i have a solidity contract with an claim function, is there a way to trigger it automatically for everyone every x time? The Claim funtion is as followed

```
   function claimDividend(address payable account) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    uint256 amount = _withdrawDividendOfUser(account);

    if(amount > 0) {
        emit Claim(account, amount);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [Chainlink Keepers](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/) (That costs a little bit of LINK on every call) or [OpenZeppelin Defender](https://openzeppelin.com/defender/) which is free.

Comment: how exactly are there tut. or smth?

Comment: Check out the links i provided

Comment: i did but how am i supposed to trigger the function above for all?

Comment: You need to specify the condition for the function to be called so either Chainlink Keepers or OpenZeppelin can call the function at the right time

Comment: i want to trigger the claim funtion for every holder